# Determining the image of a map

Tags: functions, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})\times \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$, $[a:b],[c:d]\mapsto[ac:ad:bc:bd]=[z_0:z_1:z_2:z_3]$.

How to show that $Z_0=Z(z_0z_3-z_1z_2)$ is a subset of the image of this map?

I take a point $[z_0:z_1:z_2:z_3]\in Z_0$ and I need to find its preimage.

I tried to consider two cases: $z_0=0$ and $z_0\ne 0$. The former yields $5$ subcases:

1. $(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(0,\ne 0, 0)$
2. $(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(0, \ne 0, \ne 0)$
3. $(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(\ne 0, 0, 0)$
4. $(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(\ne 0, 0, \ne 0)$
5. $(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(0,0,\ne 0)$

And the latter yields $4$ subcases:

1. $(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(0,\ne 0, 0)$
2. $(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(\ne 0, 0,0$
3. $(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(0,0,0)$
4. $(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(\ne 0, \ne 0, \ne 0)$

I concentrate on the first $5$ subcases. I managed to find preimages for cases $1$ and $3$ (they are respectively $[z_0:z_2],[1:0]$ and $[1:0],[z_0:z_1]$), but I don't know how to proceed because for example in case $2$ I need to find a preimage of $[z_0:0:z_2:z_3]$ with $z_i\ne 0$, but I think this is impossible.

Comment: What happens if you suppose $a=1$ or $b=1$?  Can you find a $b$, $c$, and $d$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353846/hartshorne-problem-1-2-14-on-segre-embedding?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $z_0\not=0$ and satisfies $z_0z_3-z_1z_2=0$.  Then, $z_3=\frac{z_1z_2}{z_0}$.  Then, we can find $a,b,c,d$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
a&=1\\
c&=z_0\\
d&=z_1\\
b&=\frac{z_2}{z_0}.
\end{align*}
Prove that the image of $[a:b]\times[c:d]$ is the same as $[z_0:z_1:z_2:z_3]$.  Continue similarly when $z_1\not=0$, $z_2\not=0$, and $z_3\not=0$ and you'll have all possible cases.

For example, if $z_1\not=0$, then $z_2=\frac{z_0z_3}{z_1}$ and we can find $a,b,c,d$ as
\begin{align*}
a&=1\\
c&=z_0\\
d&=z_1\\
b&=\frac{z_3}{z_1}.
\end{align*}

When $z_2\not=0$ or $z_3\not=0$, then start with $b=1$.

There are other ways to get this, but, from your initial elementary approach, this might be the best approach.

Comment: Thanks! But I didn't even try to consider the case $z_0\ne 0$ so far because I got stuck with the case $z_0=0$. Could you help me with this case?

Comment: Sure, but one of the $z_i$'s is nonzero.  So, rework this answer using that nonzero element.  Don't think about the zero ones, think about the nonzero ones.  This results in $4$ cases (it's ok to duplicate a case).